# concatenate dataframes one by one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

The below code reads files saves them in data frames and then concatenates all of them and after concatenation resamples data persecond. Since this is too hard on memory. What I want is to do this piece by piece. For instance I read two files concate them resample them. then read the next file concatenate it with resultant of first two files and resample and so on for 10 files, file by file. How can I change the code. Can someone help me with that.Following is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import os
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#df1 = pd.read_hdf("E:\examples\hdf files\conew1.h5", 'df')
#df2 = pd.read_hdf("E:\examples\hdf files\conew2.h5", 'df')
#df3 = pd.read_hdf("E:\examples\hdf files\conew3.h5", 'df')
hdfdirectory = "E:\examples\hdf files"
number_of_dfs=1
df=None
for fi in os.listdir(hdfdirectory):

    hdfpath =  os.path.join(hdfdirectory, fi)
    print hdfpath
    df1 = pd.read_hdf(hdfpath, 'df')

    for i in range(number_of_dfs):
        if df is None:
            df=pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':df1.timestamp , 'url' : df1.url})
            dft  = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('S').count()
        else:
            temp=pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':df1.timestamp , 'url' :df1.url})
            tempt  = temp.set_index('timestamp').resample('S').count()
            df=pd.concat([dft,tempt])
```

Comment: Consider concatenation and resample in a loop

Comment: How? can you write a short code ?

Comment: Will loading of random rows work for you?Like this https://nikgrozev.com/2015/06/16/fast-and-simple-sampling-in-pandas-when-loading-data-from-files/

Comment: No, what i want is loading of one file, resample it then load another file resample it and concatenate it with the first file. Currently i am doing it all at once, which means i am loading all the files concatenating them and resampling them. i want to load files one by one and concatenate them after resampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to create an example to illustrate my point. You might have to tweak a little but will get an idea

```
hdfdirectory = "E:\examples\hdf files"
df=None
for fi in os.listdir(hdfdirectory):

    hdfpath =  os.path.join(hdfdirectory, fi)
    print hdfpath
    df1 = pd.read_hdf(hdfpath, 'df')

    if df is None:
        df=pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':df1.timestamp , 'url' : df1.url})
        dft  = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('S').count()
        df=dft
    else:
        temp=pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':df1.timestamp , 'url' :df1.url})
        tempt  = temp.set_index('timestamp').resample('S').count()
        df=pd.concat([df,tempt])
```

Comment: I understood what you meant. but how should i do it for more than 2 files. in the above code i want to do it with 3 files but it would always concatenate first and last file. How do i modify the code so it concatenates all the files.

Comment: Why would you think this will concatenate first and last?. Can you show what you have tried ?

Comment: Yes i have edited the code in the post on top. This is the code i am using now. this concatenates dataframe 1 and 3 and not 2 since data frame 2 is overwrited by dataframe 3 . If you copy the code under my question now its doing this concatenation of first and last dataframe

Comment: you are using wrong references to the dataframe my friend during concatenation. you should be careful with the usage of `df` and `dft`. You have to concatenate the previous df and the new one and assign the value back to initial df.

Comment: Could you please modify it so it does that please.

Comment: @DanialJalil check if this helps.

Comment: Yes, it does. it works now. you are a life saver mad_